# using sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin with symfony v1.3.2/v1.4

Tags: symfony1

When I try to install the sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin, (I'm using symfony 1.3.2), I get the following error:

> No release available for plugin
>   "sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin"

Does anyone know the steps required to use this plugin with symfony 1.3.2 (or 1.4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin and click Download Package and unzip the package into your plugins directory. Make sure you enable the plugin in your project config class.

Comment: Thanks - thats what I was doing anyway, I just wanted someone to confirm that was the right way :)

Comment: I don't seem to get any JavaScript parsed into the HTML body/header of the page. Did you guys ever get it working with 1.4?